# Searchkick and remote elastic search server configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have an elastic search running on a different server (Ubuntu 14.0.4), different from my web server and database server ( Database server is on a different server as well).

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick), they suggested to set the

```
ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_URL"] = "http://username:password@api.searchbox.io"
```

and run the

```
rake searchkick:reindex CLASS=Product
```

When I do this, and run rake command, I get the following error

```
Mysql2::Error·Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your MySQL server using
`service mysqld start` or `service mariadb start`

Comment: it's looking for local mysql and I do not have mysql locally, it's on a remote server.

Comment: Then check your database.yml configuration. Or install MySQL locally.